# Centerless Polygons

Tags: code-golf, sequence, geometry, combinatorics

A [centered polygonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_polygonal_number) is a positive integer given by the number of vertices when a point is surrounded by (increasingly larger) polygons with the same number of sides, as shown below. For example, \$p_5(3) = 1 + 5 + 10 + 15 = 31\$ is a centered pentagonal number formed by taking a vertex and adding three layers of pentagons:

[image: The centered polygonal number p(5,3).]

---

This question, however, concerns center*less* polygonal numbers. In particular, we want to know how many ways we can write \$n\$ as the difference of two \$k\$-gonal numbers with \$k \geq 3\$—that is, a centered polygon with the center removed.

For example, \$35\$ can be written as the difference of two \$k\$-gonal numbers in five ways:

- \$p_5(4)    - p_5(2)    =  51 -  16\$,
- \$p_5(7)    - p_5(6)    = 141 - 106\$,
- \$p_7(3)    - p_7(1)    =  43 -   8\$,
- \$p_7(5)    - p_7(4)    = 106 -  71\$, and
- \$p_{35}(1) - p_{35}(0) =  36 -   1\$,

the first four of which are illustrated below:
[image: p_5(4) - p_5(2)]

[image: p_5(7) - p_5(6)]

[image: p_7(3) - p_7(1)]

### [image: p_7(5) - p_7(4)]

## The Challenge

This challenge will have you write a script that takes a positive integer `n` and outputs the number of ways to write \$n\$ as a center*less* polygonal number.

Since this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, the shortest code wins.

The sequence begins:

```
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 6, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 8, 3, 2, 6, 5, 1, 10, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 12, 1, 2, 5, 8, 1, 10, 1, 5, 12, 2, 1, 11, 3, 6, 5, 5, 1, 12, 5, 8, 5, 2, 1, 19, 1, 2, 12, 5, 5, 10, 1, 5, 5, 10, 1, 18, 1, 2, 12, 5, 5, 10, 1, 11, 10, 2
```

This is now in the OEIS as [A339010](https://oeis.org/A339010).

Comment: Why does `n=2` give 0? Isn't it the difference of triangular numbers 3 and 1? (Edit: Oops, I see the centered triangular numbers are a different sequence.)

Comment: @xnor—that's right. The *centered* triangular numbers are [\$A005448(n+1) = 3\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1\$](https://oeis.org/A005448), and the centered \$k\$-gonal numbers are given by \$k\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1\$.

Comment: With **uncentered** I think of something else than this one (like the images in [Wikipedia's Polygonal number article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number).) Maybe **centerless** is a better word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
:3ḍƇ⁸ÆDFḂS
```

A monadic Link accepting \$n\$ which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/K@OGO3mPtjxp3HG5zcXu4oyn4////xqYA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//OjPhuI3Gh@KBuMOGREbhuIJT/8OH4oKs//84Mg).

#### How?

```
:3ḍƇ⁸ÆDFḂS - Link: n
 3         - three
:          - (n) integer divide (3) -> x
   Ƈ       - filter keep those v in [1..x] for which:
  ḍ        -   (v) divides:
    ⁸      -     chain's left argument, n
     ÆD    - divisors (of each)
       F   - flatten
        Ḃ  - least significant bit (of each)
         S - sum
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[0^mod n q|a<-[3..n],q<-[a,3*a..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdNDkAwEAbQq3wLK6Hxs@UkTSUTFNGOUnbObrB7b6a4js6JWHAbL6@Lzm8DGPtNTa5rpdhk@yfK6pT@GfG0MFqEY@ETCTwFWOhSqaow8vTW0RQl70N4AQ)

**51 bytes**

```hs
f n=sum[1|a<-[3..n],b<-[1,3..n],c<-[1..n],a*b*c==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoAgDADAr3RwMkpEV3kJYShE1AgNEd18u1V0u@EWzNsUArMHUvmMWl44tnoQgkxjX8nmtyv@hLWtnVJkOOJKoCDtKx1QQcQEHsrqO8O38wHnzK1L6QE)

The output is the number of ways to factor \$n=abc\$ into three positive factors, where \$a \geq 3\$,  \$b\$ is odd, and \$c\$ is unconstrained.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 10 bytes

```
3÷ÝsÑÃÑÉOO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@PD2w3MPLTs16dDO4sPTas9tPTz50DK7gFp/oJQpAA) Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @ovs. Explanation:

```
3÷L         Get a list from `0` to `n//3`.
   sÑÃ      Keep only factors of `n`.
      ÑÉO   Number of odd divisors of each factor.
         O  Output the sum.
```

Comment: If you did this the same way as me, "*" is the number of odd divisors of \$n\$, which is the number of ways to write \$n\$ as the difference of two triangular numbers. (See [A001227](https://oeis.org/A001227).)

Comment: @PeterKagey Ah yes, of course; if I write `i` as the difference of two triangular numbers, this gives a solution for an `n/i`-gonal number.

Comment: I'm having some problems to relate your expl. to your output. Say, for `n = 9`, list is `1..3`, and the odd divisors/factors are `1,3`. So, sum is `4`, but output is `3`??

Comment: You can save a few bytes with the *divisors* builtin `Ñ`: [`Ñʒ3*<›}ÑÉ˜O`](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//8ORypIzKjzigLp9w5HDicucT///MzU).

Comment: @vrintle It's sum of the numbers of odd factors of the divisors of the original number. 1 has 1 odd factor. 2 is not a divisor. 3 has 2 odd factors. Total 3.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
[:+/@,[=[+/\\.@(*1+i.)~"+3+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3nmLSDdSW0imWYBMSEhNXrtwCKyNRN17AePXaUoawMenP9L2vb@blmcomaB1kIEGDC7tQcLpezr53ouxk3/aiHAbV5XsUT8W/TFTh9ny3u98eb/g4yKWaONOQR6CyPBn5xPQ4QtQaw6EI0TIupGXorKi2pNhZDHVNuiWmIb4mHlPogaComk1Ss6UWM/mIc1hNHTCZ6c/aEY/ruGYl9Waw5YHNXw6XAYz/AQ)

```
[:+/@,[=[+/\\.@(*1+i.)~"+3+i.
                           i. 0…N-1
                         3+   3…N+2
                       "+     for each y in 3…N+2:
        [      (*1+i.)~       y * 0…N, thus f.e. 5 10 15 20 … for p_5
           \\.@               take every possible sublist
         +/                   and sum it
      [=                      which sums are equal to N?
[:+/@,                        count the true bits
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

Uses [the method described by @xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215392/58563).

```javascript
f=(n,d=k=1)=>k<=n&&!(n/~++k%d)+f(n,d>n||k--&&d+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsIwEADAr6wH013SrFTxZgK@Q0RC00qbuimpCELx61HPw4z@5Zc2D/PTSApdKb1FqYONtiHr4smKUhuU3UfruA2k@786WddojFJB76m0SZY0dTylO16Y@Zyzf@PhSFd@@BnxVoMQWAe/CxoaIh7TIFhBRVS@)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (            // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,             //   n = input
  d = k = 1      //   d = odd divisor, k = other divisor
) =>             //
  k <= n &&      // stop if k is greater than n
  !(             // otherwise:
    n / ~++k     //   - increment k
    % d          //   - increment the final result if d is a divisor of n / (k + 1)
  ) +            //
  f(             // add the result of a recursive call:
    n,           //   - pass n unchanged
    d > n ||     //   - if d is greater than n, leave k unchanged and reset d to 1
    k-- && d + 2 //     otherwise, decrement k and add 2 to d
  )              // end of recursive call
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
Sum[Boole[(2i j-i)∣#],{i,3,#},{j,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P7g0N9opPz8nNVrDKFMhSzdT81HHYuVYnepMHWMd5Vqd6iwgGav2P7A0M7UkOqAoM69EQd8hXd8hKDEvPdXB0MAg9v9/AA)

*special thanks to @att for saving 20 bytes*

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P7g0N9opPz8nNVrDKFMhSzdT81HHYuVYnepMHWMd5Vqd6iwgGav2P7A0M7UkOqAoM69EQd8hXd8hKDEvPdXB0MAg9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＦθＦθＦθ⊞υ×⁺³ι×⊕⊗κ⊕λＩ№υθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IAchQQKcDSoszNEp1FEIyc1OLNQJySos1jHUUMjVhIp55yUWpual5JakpGi75pUk5QDpbEyiNLJGjCQTWXAFFmXklGs6JxUAivxTIBJpbCJL5/9/Y9L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @xnor's answer. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
ＦθＦθＦθ
```

Create loops `i`, `k` and `l` ranging from `0` to `n`.

```
⊞υ×⁺³ι×⊕⊗κ⊕λ
```

Calculate `a*b*c` where `a=i+3`, `b=2k+1` and `c=l+1`.

```
Ｉ№υθ
```

Count how many times this equals `n`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>84</s> 65 bytes

Saved a whopping 19 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
lambda n,R=range:sum(n%q<1for a in R(3,n+1)for q in R(a,n+1,2*a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwELzzFXupsBsqZU2gNCr9iFyTHFxiGquJQ4BIrRDfTm3DIi61VtbO7OxDU/2255uJhzI/DBd5/TxJMNEur6X5UtvmcWXm6f6O5a0GCdrAjsWRWSF3xH0kpCMi8Sw5H9RPpYpWnSAHto7ABlII@mPKE2IST9o8JT4hTUb6lPQ4Dt2QyLFiMSlbqqbiWEf0w1LagGNx7Jk34tt8rpiV68VhE8DsXx1OBwgeFGdVfKva@REeHuJ1U4QR@AzjkAfORu1s9H6zizKMLOR8G4B9xvZqWAF61FhUMsM9UBaQfK@PnqtqbVpWhp3p4eUDuqaHbjpir/K8OfYhH/4A)

Uses [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s method from his [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215392/9481).

Comment: xnor's more compact function comes in at [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwELzzFXupsBsqZU2gNCr9iFyTHFxiGquJQ4BIrRDfTm3DIi61VtbO7OxDU/2255uJhzI/DBd5/TxJMNEur6X5UtvmcWXm6f6O5a0GCdrAjsWRWSF3xH0kpCMi8Sw5H9RPpYpWnSAHto7ABlII@mPKE2IST9o8JT4hTUb6lPQ4Dt2QyLFiMSlbqqbiWEf0w1LagGNx7Jk34tt8rpiV68VhE8DsXx1OBwgeFGdVfKva@REeHuJ1U4QR@AzjkAfORu1s9H6zizKMLOR8G4B9xvZqWAF61FhUMsM9UBaQfK@PnqtqbVpWhp3p4eUDuqaHbjpir/K8OfYhH/4A) in Python.

Comment: @ovs Oh wow - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 49 bytes

```
.+
$*
M!&`(.+)$(?<=^\1{3,})
m&`(.(..)*)$(?<=^\1+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@nzaWixeWrqJYAZPkncKlq@CYYIolq6GlrqmjY29jGxRhWG@vUanLlggQ19PQ0teAS2pr//xubAgA) Link includes test suite that checks all numbers from `1` to the input. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M!&`(.+)$(?<=^\1{3,})
```

List (`!`) all (`&`) factors not greater than `n/3`.

```
m&`(.(..)*)$(?<=^\1+)
```

Count the number of odd factors of all the factors. (The `M` is implicit as this is the last stage.)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>79</s> <s>63</s></sup> 62 bytes

Saved a whopping 16 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
a;q;s;f(n){for(s=0,q=a=3;n/q||n/(q=++a);)s+=n%(q-=2*a)<1;n=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLRboIwFH33K25ITFqBSHEaTO1e3L5i@EBqUbKtCjUZmfLrYwV6mT6MlOb23HNPL@ciw4OUbZvxkhueE02v@akiRkRBKTKx4Hpe3m56Tkrh@xnl1PhCT0kZiniW0Q3jWhjetIW@wGdWaEIn1wnYpwNUfVbyovZvOxBwjQKwi@GKcV9gvERk2YM2XiG@RE6C/BXy2SD6hKQOje@UknuWSw55xnqxFd7AhuRQM97I1mO78ciM7hpzB5b8y2OugbjhvTfymFUzeVTyXVXWG@jc8dL6NU7r9UtaJ1svADxv7bvwXKGdDJDO2ULvVW3LIu7CDZjiW51ygp7TuQNmI8LB93s2hWFGOCdtlQYZHxh/SBmb6n6KR1RZdBxuX7n7I5wrS8mJN91D@Ax2n5pUe4EOwASAX22EUDun2kya9kfmH9nBtOHXLw)

Uses [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s method from his [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215392/9481).

Comment: @ovs Used your observation on using xnor's more compact function in this answer too - thanks! :D

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVLRboIwFH33K25ITFqBSHEaTO1e3L5i@EBqUbKtCjUZmfLrYwV6mT6MlOb23HNPL@ciw4OUbZvxkhueE02v@akiRkRBKTKx4Hpe3m56Tkrh@xnl1PhCT0kZiniW0Q3jWhjetIW@wGdWaEIn1wnYpwNUfVbyovZvOxBwjQKwi@GKcV9gvERk2YM2XiG@RE6C/BXy2SD6hKQOje@UknuWSw55xnqxFd7AhuRQM97I1mO78ciM7hpzB5b8y2OugbjhvTfymFUzeVTyXVXWG@jc8dL6NU7r9UtaJ1svADxv7bvwXKGdDJDO2ULvVW3LIu7CDZjiW51ygp7TuQNmI8LB93s2hWFGOCdtlQYZHxh/SBmb6n6KR1RZdBxuX7n7I5wrS8mJN91D@Ax2n5pUe4EOwASAX22EUDun2kya9kfmH9nBtOHXLw) with a single `for` loop.

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 76 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n/3).select{|k|n%k==0}.sum{|o|(1..o).select{|i|o%i==0}.sum{|j|j%2}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9P31hTrzg1JzW5pLomuyZPNdvW1qBWr7g0t7omvwakIh8hn1mTr5qJkM@qyVI1qq2t/Z@WX6SQqZCZpwBUbmrApaCgUKCQFp0Zy5Wal/IfAA)

Based on Neil's answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 73 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0,a=2,t;for(;a++<n;)for(t=a;t<=n;t+=2*a)if(n%t<1)r++;return r;}
```

Port of [*@Noodle9*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215406/52210), which uses the same method as [*@xnor*'s Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215392/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVJRS8MwEH73VxwFoTFbaaobdWkEER/di4/iQ@wyyezSmaZDGfvtNblmMBClNMl9333f3TXdyL2cblYfQ93IroMnqc3hAkAbp@xa1gqWIUQA6jSshnCPHC/80jnpdA1LMCBgMNO7Q0iwIp9IUUwcX7c25ZLSynASzk5I7iphuKOiuJJEr1Nz6SpGLKXcKtdbA5YfBx7Md/1b481jjX2rV7D13aXPzmrz/vIKkoytjQCor52qnVr5VpIccmD4FPhe4z7D88xHDOYYzxAvkZ8jz4LwBgkfFlFRnhjEAsqYF83RggUs5Ixu7HYsW4xkHgvhgZW/OIbOBSR8HOa7c2qbtb3Ldn4s15g0eYyTLSChpykJP59d1q6XTZg82oSvHe5CC8ZBV6Is/EYpQRJiPhUm83dKaPJf9XvMXXg2oaOO/J380Frr@zvvNFOfXtOlURv/nuPwAw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{               // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int r=0,         //  Result-sum, starting at 0
      a=2,         //  Temp-integer `a`, starting at 2
      t;           //  Temp-integer `t`, uninitialized
  for(;a++<n;)     //  Loop `a` in the range [1, n]:
    for(t=a;t<=n;  //   Inner loop `t` in the range [a, n],
        t+=2*a)    //   in increments of 2a
      if(n%t<1)    //    If the input is evenly divisible by `t`:
        r++;       //     Increase the result-sum by 1
  return r;}       //  And after the loops, return the result-sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>40</s> 33 bytes (SBCS)

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @[Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!*

Port of Neil's 05AB1E [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215389/95792).

```apl
{+/∊(⊢(|⍨<2|⊢)1+⍳)¨⍵(⊢∩∨)⍳1+⌊⍵÷3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6u19R91dGk86lqkUfOod4WNUQ2QqWmo/ah3s@ahFY96t4KkHnWsfNSxQhMoBpTo6QKKHt5uXPs/DWjCo96@R13Nj3rXPOrdcmi98aO2iUCzg4OcgWSIh2fw/7RDK8CGGZsCAA)

```apl
{+/∊(⊢(|⍨<2|⊢)1+⍳)¨⍵(⊢∩∨)⍳1+⌊⍵÷3}
                          ⍳1+⌊⍵÷3 ⍝ Range to n//3 + 1
                    ⍵(⊢∩∨)       ⍝ Keep divisors of n
                   ¨              ⍝ For each divisor
   ∊(⊢(|⍨<2|⊢)1+⍳)               ⍝ A train to find odd divisors of the divisor, not sure how it works exactly
               1+⍳)               ⍝ Make a range from 2 to the divisor+1
    (⊢                           ⍝ On this side, just give back the divisor
      (|⍨<2|⊢)                   ⍝ Checks that the element of the range divides the divisor and that it's odd
      (|⍨                        ⍝ The possible divisor mod its divisor
         <                       ⍝ Is less than
          2|⊢)                   ⍝ 2 mod the divisor's possible divisor
   ∊                             ⍝ Turn into vector so a single sum is needed
 +/                               ⍝ Sum that
```

Comment: [33 bytes (SBCS)](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXNXa@o86ugxsqx/1bq151LvCUNvo8PRHvZsf9XQARQ5vN6o9tALI0HjUtehRx8pHHSs0gZKG2o96usDSxrVQE6o1jB51zKixqwGSQBlNoBKgIb1bidUOUgSy38aoBqiWaO3/IdpBCjC0axLSmwYMgUe9fY@6mh/1rnnUu@XQeuNHbROBYRMc5AwkQzw8g/@nHVoBNszYFAA) using `⎕IO←0`.

Comment: Any reason [you only requested](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/43319) 50 rep for this?

Comment: @Adám It didn't qualify for any of the multipliers - it's not the shortest answer here, and I can't explain it very well. Actually, I should probably remove the request, since it was posted in 2020

Comment: @user But your code is fully explained!

Comment: @Adám To quote myself: "∊ ⍝ I don't know why this is here". I guess I can probably find out how it works through a bit of work, but this question doesn't currently qualify for your bounty, and anyway, I got a 100 rep bounty from you already :)

Comment: `∊` is **e**nlist a.k.a. flatten. Check out [APLcart](https://aplcart.info/?q=monadic%20%E2%88%8A%20primitive#).

Comment: @Adám Ah, I should probably have done that in the first place. I looked at the tooltip just now for it in Dyalog and saw there was also a monadic form

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
3/╒÷mÉî*──¥Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/99Y/9HUSYe35x7uPLxO69GUBiA6tPTc4v//DbmMuIy5TLhMucy4zLksuCy5DA24jEy5jE25TA24zE2BXAMA)

**Explanation:**

```python
3/           # Integer-divide the (implicit) input-integer by 3
  ╒          # Pop and push a list in the range [0, input//3]
   ÷         # Check for each that they evenly divide the (implicit) input
             # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    m        # Then map each boolean to,
     É       # using the following three characters as inner code-block:
      î*     #  Multiply the boolean by the 1-based map-index
        ─    #  Pop and push a list of its divisors
         ─   # Flatten this list of list of integers
          ¥  # Modulo-2 on each
           Σ # And sum those together
             # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```